# stack or global data (heap) - which one is better for allocating data objects to registers

Tags: architecture, cpu-architecture

Current programming languages store data in stack, global data area or heap. In which case allocating data objects to registers will be effective and why?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in allocating data to registers. The compiler must be able to deal with possible aliases, proving that two names never reference the same datum, proving that two names always reference the same datum, or determining if dynamic alias handling is less expensive than the benefit of register allocation. The compiler must also estimate the cost to benefit of retaining a datum in a register.

(In a load-store instruction set, all data is allocated to a register, albeit for a very short time in some cases.)

Local (stack) data are the easiest to allocate to registers because their scope is relatively limited (so analyzing use over their lifetimes is simpler) and they are usually easily proven not to alias.

Alias analysis for global data is often less difficult than for heap data, but the scope of use is typically less restricted than for stack data so the cost/benefit analysis is more difficult. (In C, function and file static data--which are 'global'--have a localized scope making alias and cost/benefit analyses simpler.)

Heap data is generally both least friendly to alias analysis (because it is often difficult to prove no aliasing for code in a C-like language) and less friendly to cost/benefit analysis (since the use is less constrained than for local/stack data).